# Powershell Script Outputs blank when run on PHP

Tags: php, apache, shell, powershell, xampp

I am kind of new to both PHP and Powershell.
I made a website to run a powershell script , which checks multiple server file directory and returns the items in that directory.
On the website they display on a organized data table.

My issue is that when php exec() calls on the script, it runs but the data output is blank. Why does this happen when php runs the script?

Here is the powershell file.
I even added some credential sessions, thinking it must be a credentials issue.

```
  Remove-PSDrive target: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $global:username = "domain\user"
  $global:password = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "MyPassword" –AsPlainText -Force
  $global:cred = new-object -typename       System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $global:username,  $global:password


   $output_Table = @()
   $today = get-date
   $html_output =@()
   $tableData=@()


  New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $global:cred -Root "\\serverName\filedir" | Out-Null
 $tableData+= '<table><tr><th>First Feed</th><th>Updates:DAILY</th></tr> <tr><th>FileName</th><th>FileDate</th></tr>'
 foreach ($file in (ls target:)) 
 {GetFeed(-7)}
 $tableData +='</table>'
 Remove-PSDrive -Name target -Force


 $html_output += $tableData
 $html_output += '</div>'

 $html_output | Out-File "C:\xampp\htdocs\script_results.txt" -Encoding utf8
 $today | Out-file "C:\xampp\htdocs\script_TimeStamp.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

The script_result.txt has the files with the HTML tags. PHP will later read this and echo it into the html page.

The PHP code that calls on this script is the following.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  set_time_limit (300);
  $output = array();
  $return_code = 0;
  $last_line = exec('powershell.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\script.ps1  2>&1 ', $output, $return_code);

  } ?>
```

later on theres this piece of code to display the results.
Once again, if i run the powershell script myself, it returns the script_result with the desired output.
If PHP runs it, the script runs, but the output has no file data in it.

What is causing this?

Comment: maybe a permission issue. The user php is running should have the permissions to do what you want.

Comment: When I'm testing it, im looking at my task manager. I see the powershell.exe pop up with my user name on it. :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact dynamically with a real Powershell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shellObj    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('powershell');

$strCmd1   = 'Remove-PSDrive target: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue';
$return1  = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd1);

$strCmd2   = '$global:username = "domain\user"';
$return2  = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd2);

//etc, etc
```

This way you can issue each individual command and handle the return, if it is a permissions issue the command that fails will return the error message from Powershell. You can issue any command you like against the $shellObj, the environment is maintained throughout the life of the PHP script.